# Some parts of this C code doesn't make sense for me

Tags: c

Hi considering this code:

```
uint16_t dest_pid;
uint8_t *p;

pf->dest_pid = p[0] + (p[1] << 8)   //(p[1] << 8) equals 0 right?
```

This code is a part of embedded operating system's driver. 
Some ideas what might be the idea behind that statement? Or may be I am missing something essential?

Comment: Dereferencing uninitialised pointer?? Not sure what the idea is there but its not a good idea thats for sure. Unless you are missing out some code?

Comment: `(p[1] << 8) ` is (part of) an expression. It has a type (unsigned), which is *derived* from `p[1]`s type: it only "inherits" the unsigned quality, not the size.

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12131568/bit-shifting-a-byte-by-more-than-8-bit

Comment: why do you think it's 0?

Comment: because it is uint8_t type meaning it is 8bit
1111 1111 << 8 equals 0000 0000

Comment: @RadoslawKrasimirow Forget about variables; they are lower life forms. The C syntax is about values and expressions. Variables only exist to serve as basic blocks for these.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: `dest_pid` after `pf` is part from structure and I think it is another variable then `uint16_t dest_pid;`

Second: `p` is a pointer to `uint8_t`, when you do `(p[1] << 8)` you shift what is inside the pointer by 8, for example if `p[1] = 0xE5` after shifting it will be `0xE500`. Remember that you put your result in `dest_pid` which is a 2 bytes variable.

The translation of the last line is most likely to take the low byte (less significant) of `pid` and add it to the high byte(shifted by 8) of `pid` and put it in `pf->dest_pid`, you may think why he didn't send 2 bytes from the beginning, and the reason for that may be because he is getting it from a bus which sends only a byte per unit of time(cycle).

Answer (score 8):

I assume that your `p` is meaningfully initialized (to point to some valid location).

Then in `p[0] + (p[1] << 8)` the `p[1]` would be implicitly promoted to `unsigned` before doing the left shift `<< 8`, so the code does make sense (e.g. on 32 bits processors like ARM). Informally it makes a 16 bit number whose lower 8 bits are from `p[0]` and higher 8 bits are from `p[1]`

Grossly speaking, the implicit rule is that in C arithmetic operations are on `int` at least (and never on smaller pieces of data like `short` or `uint8_t` or `char`). But the details are more complex (and have slightly evolved from C89 to C99 and to C11 standards).

Comment: Assuming type `uint8_t`, the `p[1]` would be implicitly casted to `int` (or `signed` if you prefer), because of _integer promotions_. There is no other way around in this case.

Comment: That's correct, but the type of p[whatever is inside ] is eight bits.
If it was explicitly casted as   ".. + (uint16_t)(p[1]<<8)" I would understand, it would be equal to p[1] * 256. For now I only see this "(eight_bit_var << 8)" which (for me) means zero.

Comment: @RadoslawKrasimirow: you are wrong: `(eightbitvar << 8)` is not an 8 bits operand shift, but an `int` shift. So it is not always zero.

Comment: It might help if you added a reference to the C standard's "usual arithmetic conversions" language.

Comment: Terminology quirk: there's no such thing as *implicit casting*. Casts are always explicit. What happens here are *promotions* or *conversions*.